# Python script for batch processing for forecast of group of SKUs

Tags: python, loops

I am looking for some help on time series forecasting. I have some 10 SKU products(SKUs are in First column) which has 36 months sales data (which is spread across from 2nd column to 37th column. (snap is provided as an image)
I would need to apply some time series forecasting techniques like snaive, ARIMA, Holt's, SES, MA to these 10 SKU products to generate Forecast of next 3 months and
have excel download from data frame
Expected result: 3 months forecast for these 10 SKUs and excel export
but I'm not getting the desired result - getting forecast basis 24 months sales data only

Please let me know what is amiss.

data used:

```
SKU     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
SKU1    11  92  72  18  42  26  4   93  81  41  39  80  13  94  74  20  44  28  6   95  83  43  41  82  15  96  76  22  46  30  8   97  85  45  43  84
SKU2    33  38  84  1   62  72  64  22  28  34  73  10  35  40  86  3   64  74  66  24  30  36  75  12  37  42  88  5   66  76  68  26  32  38  77  14
SKU3    93  75  11  63  4   68  65  86  7   55  32  6   95  77  13  65  6   70  67  88  9   57  34  8   97  79  15  67  8   72  69  90  11  59  36  10
SKU4    90  42  35  72  71  53  56  17  7   54  12  66  92  44  37  74  73  55  58  19  9   56  14  68  94  46  39  76  75  57  60  21  11  58  16  70
SKU5    38  42  20  27  43  74  73  37  73  53  2   28  40  44  22  29  45  76  75  39  75  55  4   30  42  46  24  31  47  78  77  41  77  57  6   32
SKU6    32  65  61  35  29  52  82  86  47  1   73  91  34  67  63  37  31  54  84  88  49  3   75  93  36  69  65  39  33  56  86  90  51  5   77  95
SKU7    47  13  30  83  99  8   75  34  69  33  13  54  49  15  32  85  101 10  77  36  71  35  15  56  51  17  34  87  103 12  79  38  73  37  17  58
SKU8    36  35  34  33  32  31  30  29  28  27  26  25  24  23  22  21  20  19  18  17  16  15  14  13  12  11  10  9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1
SKU9    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
SKU10   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
```

Script used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.api import SimpleExpSmoothing, ExponentialSmoothing, SARIMAX
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Load data
data = pd.read_csv('sales_data.csv', index_col=0)

# Loop over all SKUs
for sku in data.index:
    print(f"Forecasting SKU: {sku}")
    
    # Get the sales data for this SKU
    sales_data = data.loc[sku].values
    
    # Split data into training and testing sets
    train_size = 24  # Use the first 24 months as training data
    train_data, test_data = sales_data[:train_size], sales_data[train_size:]
    
    # Simple Naive method
    naive_forecast = train_data[-1]
    naive_preds = np.repeat(naive_forecast, len(test_data))
    naive_mse = mean_squared_error(test_data, naive_preds)
    naive_forecast_values = np.repeat(naive_forecast, len(sales_data) - train_size)
    
    # ARIMA model
    arima_model = SARIMAX(train_data, order=(1, 0, 1), seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12), enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
    arima_results = arima_model.fit()
    arima_preds = arima_results.forecast(steps=len(test_data))
    arima_mse = mean_squared_error(test_data, arima_preds)
    arima_forecast_values = arima_results.forecast(steps=len(sales_data) - train_size)
    
    # Holt's method
    holt_model = ExponentialSmoothing(train_data, trend='add', seasonal='add', seasonal_periods=12)
    holt_results = holt_model.fit()
    holt_preds = holt_results.forecast(steps=len(test_data))
    holt_mse = mean_squared_error(test_data, holt_preds)
    holt_forecast_values = holt_results.forecast(steps=len(sales_data) - train_size)
    
    # Simple Exponential Smoothing (SES)
    ses_model = SimpleExpSmoothing(train_data)
    ses_results = ses_model.fit()
    ses_preds = ses_results.forecast(steps=len(test_data))
    ses_mse = mean_squared_error(test_data, ses_preds)
    ses_forecast_values = ses_results.forecast(steps=len(sales_data) - train_size)
    
    # Moving Average (MA)
    ma_model = ExponentialSmoothing(train_data, trend=None, seasonal='add', seasonal_periods=12)
    ma_results = ma_model.fit()
    ma_preds = ma_results.forecast(steps=len(test_data))
    ma_mse = mean_squared_error(test_data, ma_preds)
    ma_forecast_values = ma_results.forecast(steps=len(sales_data) - train_size)
    
    # Print results
    print(f"Naive MSE: {naive_mse:.2f}")
    print(f"ARIMA MSE: {arima_mse:.2f}")
    print(f"Holt's MSE: {holt_mse:.2f}")
    print(f"SES MSE: {ses_mse:.2f}")
    print(f"MA MSE: {ma_mse:.2f}")
    print(f"Naive Forecast Values: {naive_forecast_values}")
    print(f"ARIMA Forecast Values: {arima_forecast_values}")
    print(f"Holt's Forecast Values: {holt_forecast_values}")
    print(f"SES Forecast Values: {ses_forecast_values}")
    print(f"MA Forecast Values: {ma_forecast_values}")

# Create a dictionary with SKU names as keys and forecasted values as values
forecast_dict = {'Naive': naive_forecast_values.round(),
                 'ARIMA': arima_forecast_values.round(),
                 'Holt': holt_forecast_values.round(),
                 'SES': ses_forecast_values.round(),
                 'MA': ma_forecast_values.round()}

# Convert the dictionary to a pandas dataframe
forecast_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(forecast_dict, orient='columns')

# Save the dataframe to an Excel file
forecast_df.to_excel('forecast.xlsx', index_label='SKU')
```

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: I'm getting result basis 24 months sales data (not 36 months basis) and for every forecasting model I'm getting 3 months forecast.
out put :
SKU snaive arima holt ses ma
SKU1 [82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82] [47.65391601 51.30031661 50.91319133] [58.03531087 58.60487483 59.17443878] [50.91666917 50.91666917 50.91666917] [40.83747466  0.          0.        ]